# laravel pagination on post

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

hi :) im parsing my database in a table with pagination !!

this is my controller

```
$theme = Theme::all();
            $questions = questionList::paginate(10);
            $the = "";
            return View::make('home.home')
            ->with('user',Auth::user())
            ->with('theme', $theme)
            ->with('the' ,  $the)
            ->with('questions',$questions);
```

and my view  i have `{{ $questions->links(); }}` under my table and it's working fine !!
the thing is that i have a list of themes to sort data in the table so when i click on divertisement i get divertisement data.
 the problem is that when i paginate it return to the get request and give me all the data !! what is the problem thx :)

Answer (score 1):

To add a `filter/sort` you also need to add that in a `where` clause in your `query` and also you need to append the `query string` in your pagination links. For example:

```
public function showPosts()
{
    $questions = app('questionList');

    if($filter = Input::get('filter')) {
        $questions = $questions->where('theme', $filter);
    }

    $questions = $questions->paginate(10);

    if(isset($filter)) {
        $questions->appends('filter', $filter);
    }

    return View::make(...)->with(...);
}
```

In your `view` you need to create links to this method (Probably using a route name or url) with `filter` query string. So, for example:

```
<a href="{{ 'link to that method' }}?filter=divertisement">Divertisement</a>
<a href="{{ 'link to that method' }}?filter=SomethingElse">SomethingElse</a>
```